How to retrieve direct URL requests from the Windows Taskbar?
How can I monitor all of the URL requests inside of the Windows taskbar that are requesting for direct file links? For example, when the date changes, and the Search Highlights image changes to the next one, is there a way to see what URL it is requesting?
The Search Highlights picture is an SVG link.
Same goes for the News & Interests icons that change randomly and include animated icons.
This icon is also an SVG link, most of the time.

I'm sure procmon can monitor this. Its a free tool from Microsoft themselves.

Does procmon include internet URLs? News & Interests is entirely based around online requests.

It shows so much, including registry access, file access, etc.

How do you check for visited website URLS?
